# is there any wordpress plugin for MCQ questions not quiz?

Tags: wordpress

I have an website [stuffarrow.com](http://stuffarrow.com) in wordpress. I have to post some Multiple choice questions(MCQ). I searched the wordpress plugin directory with "mcq" there are hardly 2 plugins and they are not relevant.

Can someone please help me to find out any plugin for MCQ in plugin. there are lot of quiz plugins available, but not able to find the MCQ plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I had developed wordpress-based E-learning apps in the past and used the [Sensei plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/sensei/). This extension has cool features among which the Multiple Choice Question. You can see it in action in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcXvVBrpnAI.

There is also [WP-Pro Quiz plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/) which has a MCQ feature, however this plugin hasn't been updated for years.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stackoverflow for your support. I got this plugin wp-showhide. this  plugin solved my purpose.